# C#のLinq csv結合について

Tags: c#, csv, linq

C#のLinqについて質問です。msのサイトのコードを参考に、二つのcsvファイルをinner joinで繋げて出力させるコードを書きました。
 コード中ではフィールド0からフィールド4までの出力になっていますが、これを全フィールド出力させるにはどうしたらよいですか？（フィールドは全部で200以上あり、個別での記載は難しいです）
 以下、コードです。よろしくお願いします。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class JoinStrings {
    static void Main() {
        string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test\aa\names.csv", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));
        string[] scores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test\aa\scores.csv", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));

        IEnumerable<string> scoreQuery1 =
            from name in names
            let nameFields = name.Split(',')
            from id in scores
            let scoreFields = id.Split(',')
            where nameFields[0] == scoreFields[3]
            select nameFields[0] + "," + scoreFields[1] + "," + scoreFields[2]
                    + "," + scoreFields[3] + "," + scoreFields[4];

        OutputQueryResults(scoreQuery1, "Merge two spreadsheets:");

        // Keep console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void OutputQueryResults(IEnumerable<string> query, string message) {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + message);
        foreach (string item in query) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} total names in list", query.Count());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

まず[String.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx)を使うことでさまざまな結合ができます。とはいえ単一の配列かIEnumerableが必要になるため、Enumerable.Concat()で結合するとよいでしょう。

```
var names = from name in File.ReadLines(@"C:\test\aa\names.csv", Encoding.Default)
            select name.Split(',');
var scores = from score in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test\aa\scores.csv", Encoding.Default)
             select score.Split(',');

var scoreQuery1 = from name in names
                  join score in scores on name[0] equals score[3]
                  select String.Join(",", new[] { name[0] }.Concat(score));
```

[EnumerableEx.StartWith()](https://github.com/Applied-Duality/Rx/blob/master/Ix/NET/Source/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx.Single.cs#L483)を使うともう少しきれいにかけます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！望み通りに動作しました。こんなに美しくかけるとは驚きでした。すばらしいです！